# Scaling and inverse scaling numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, equation

I am reposting this to be way better worded

I am building a discord bot for me and my buddies to play inhouses with (private 5v5s). It drafts teams, records score, and keeps a leaderboard with a crappy rating system

Everyone on the winning team gains the same amount of rating as everyone on the losing team loses. You can gain/lose a maximum of 75 elo for an underdog win and gain/lose a minimum of 25 for a clear favorite win.

Basically if you win a game you are favored to win you gain 25 - 49 elo depending on the elo difference.

If you win a game you were the underdog in you gain 51-75 elo.

There are only 30-40 of us so an actual ELO system would not work and its just for fun.

I'm still very new to coding so for whatever reason I just cant seem to wrap my head around how to calculate this.

This is the totally wrong equation i have so far

```
var loserELO = process.argv[2];
var winnerELO = process.argv[3];
var eloUpdate

//if loser has more elo than winner
if (winnerELO != loserELO) {

    if (winnerELO > loserELO) {
        var diff = winnerELO - loserELO;
        var percent = diff / 750
        eloUpdate = diff * 75

    }
    if (loserELO > winnerELO) {

        var diff = winnerELO / loserELO;
        eloUpdate = diff * 75;
    }



    if (eloUpdate > 75) {
        eloUpdate = 75;
    }

    if (eloUpdate < 25) {
        eloUpdate = 25;
    }
}
else {
    eloUpdate = 50
}
console.log(eloUpdate);
```

Comment: Why would this work better than actual Elo?

Comment: @Ry- well, i think actual elo is really meant for 1v1, something i should have mentioned is that these teams are 4v4 or 5v5 depending on the game. Also with such a small community most conventional rating systems won't work. Acolyte fight is a good example of a small community where the rating system sucks because of how small it is.

I'm no expert on the subject so maybe im completely wrong

Answer (score 0):

Hello I figured it out and was making it way more complicated than I needed to.

```
var winnerELO = process.argv[2];
var loserELO = process.argv[3];

var eloDiff = loserELO - winnerELO;
var eloUpdate;

var xMax = 75;
var xMin = 25;

var yMax = 1500;
var yMin = -1500;

var percent = (eloDiff - yMin) / (yMax - yMin);
eloUpdate = percent * (xMax - xMin) + xMin;

if (eloUpdate > 75) {
    eloUpdate = 75;
}
if (eloUpdate < 25) {
    eloUpdate = 25;
}

console.log(eloUpdate);
```